# UINavigationBar has wrong height on rotation in Action Extension

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I wrote a little app that includes an action extension. 
Now I am struggling with a rotation issue.

In the beginning, the navigationBar looks like it should. [image]

After I rotate the device, the navigation bar keeps its height, while the status bar disappears. 
[image]

When I rotate back, the navigation bar is now 44 points hight, like it should be in landscape.
[image]

I uploaded a [small project](https://github.com/mangerlahn/NavigationBar-Test) to demonstrate the problem to you. I recognized that the Dropbox action extension has the same bug.

The view controller is embedded in a `UINavigationController`

I assume somewhere down the path forgot to call super. 
Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: implement preferStatusBarHidden method in view Controller class and return NO in that method and check.

Comment: Now the status bar is visible all the time (obviously). It is not the default appearance in landscape but it fixes my problem, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was experiencing a similar issue. In my case I had a `UINavigationController`. I was presenting a view controller from a child view controller of `UINavigationController`. After presentation, when I rotated the device, the height of navigation bar was screwed up.

**What I did**

Instead of presenting a view controller from a child view controller of `UINavigationController`, I presented it from the `UINavigationController` itself. It fixed the problem.